# In PowerShell is there a way to inspect and print the function name where the breakpoint hit in the action block?

Tags: powershell

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable idx -Mode Write -Action { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "MyAction: $($idx)"
}

Function Test ($p) {

    0..$p | % {
        $idx = $_
        $idx
    }
}

Test 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $MyInvocation e.g.:

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable idx -Mode Write -Action {  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name): $($idx)" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. I tried $MyInvocation.ScriptNamem and of course it didn't work.